# Completer with international characters

Tags: python, autocomplete

I'm using the following code for text completion:

```
class MyCompleter(object):  # Custom completer

    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = sorted(options) 

    def complete(self, text, state):
        if state == 0:  # on first trigger, build possible matches
            if text:  # cache matches (entries that start with entered text)
                self.matches = [s for s in self.options
                                    if s and s.startswith(text)]
            else:  # no text entered, all matches possible
                self.matches = self.options[:]
        # return match indexed by state
        try: 
            return self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None

def setCompleter(listOfItems):
  readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
  readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')
  completer = MyCompleter(listOfItems)
  readline.set_completer(completer.complete)
```

The options are taken from the database. When I need to make a completion it
does not offer options than contain international characters with [diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).
Can I customize the code to offer options that contain diacritic too?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using Python2; in Python3 this probably "just works".

Your database is returning `unicode` objects, which the `readline` library converts to string before use. This conversion uses, by default, the ascii codec, which works fine for `u"Name"`, but fails for `u"Näme"`.

It *might* help to replace this line:

```
completer = MyCompleter([item.encode('utf-8') for item in listOfItems])
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python2